# crash while try store value using dependency inversion

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, solid-principles, dependency-inversion

I want to implemented dependency inversion In app delegate in my app as my `rootController` is my `UITabBarController` but when I want to try it there is an error

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value

This is my code in my appDelagate

```
let exploreStore = ExploreStore()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let rootController = (window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController)?.children.first as? ExploreViewController
    // Inject Data
    rootController?.exploreStore = exploreStore
    return true
}
```

This is my explore class

```
class ExploreStore {
    fileprivate var allItems = [ExploreItem]()
    func fetch() {
        for data in loadData() {
            allItems.append(ExploreItem(dict: data))
        }
    }
    func numberOfItem() -> Int {
        return allItems.count
    }
    func explore(at index: IndexPath) -> ExploreItem {
        return allItems[index.item]
    }
    fileprivate func loadData() -> [[String: AnyObject]] {
        guard
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ExploreData", ofType: "plist"),
            let items = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
        else { return [[:]] }
        return items as! [[String: AnyObject]]
    }
}
```

This is my exlporeViewController

```
var exploreStore: ExploreStore!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // This is where the error found nil
    exploreStore.fetch()
}
```

Actually the code work if I don't use dependency inversion, like my explore view controller not use force unwrapping like this

```
var exploreStore = ExploreStore()
```

but since I want gain knowledge and learn S.O.L.I.D principle using dependency inversion, I want to stick with this principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want to initialise your class at `AppDelegate` class and then you want to pass it to your `UITabBarController`'s first `children` and for that you need to make some modifications into your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method like shown below:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar")
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    let myTabBar = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let firstViewController = myTabBar.children.first as? FirstViewController
    firstViewController?.exploreStore = exploreStore
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Here I have made some modification's because I am retrieving `Info.plist` from `Bundle` and your `ExploreStore` will look like:

```
class ExploreStore {

    var allItems = [ExploreItem]()

    func fetch() {
        if let dataObjectFromPlist = loadData() {
            allItems.append(ExploreItem(dict: dataObjectFromPlist))
        }
    }
    func numberOfItem() -> Int {
        return allItems.count
    }
    func explore(at index: IndexPath) -> ExploreItem {
        return allItems[index.item]
    }
    fileprivate func loadData() -> [String: AnyObject]? {

        var resourceFileDictionary: [String: AnyObject]?
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist") {
            if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                resourceFileDictionary = dict
            }
        }
        return resourceFileDictionary
    }
}
```

Then in my `FirstViewController` I can fetch the data from `ExploreStore` class with

```
exploreStore.fetch()
```

and my code for that `UIViewController` is

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var exploreStore: ExploreStore!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        exploreStore.fetch()
        print(exploreStore.allItems[0].data)
    }
}
```

Here `exploreStore.allItems[0].data` will print my whole `info.plist` file.

You can try it by your self with [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=76067509418743662052) demo project and check if that's the correct behaviour.

**EDIT**

You need to update `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    setupDefaultColors()

    let exploreStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Explore", bundle:nil)
    let navigationController = exploreStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExploreViewControllerNavigation") as! UINavigationController
    if let exploreViewController = navigationController.children.first as? ExploreViewController {
        exploreViewController.store = ExploreStore()
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = exploreViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

And you also need to update `ExploreStore` class as shown below:

```
class ExploreStore {

    var allItems = [ExploreItem]()

    func fetch() {
        if let dataObjectFromPlist = loadData() {
            allItems.append(ExploreItem(dict: dataObjectFromPlist))
        }
    }

    func numberOfItem() -> Int {
        return allItems.count
    }

    func explore(at index: IndexPath) -> ExploreItem {
        return allItems[index.item]
    }

    fileprivate func loadData() -> [String: AnyObject]? {
        var resourceFileDictionary: [String: AnyObject]?
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ExploreData", ofType: "plist") {
            if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                resourceFileDictionary = dict
            }
        }
        return resourceFileDictionary
    }
}
```

Because from `plist` you will get `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` type object.

And you will still not get data from `plist` file because its added into subfolder. So you need find correct path first for your `plist`.

You also needs to assign respective identifiers to navigation controller and tab bar controller.

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=56699203668877824080) is your demo project.

Comment: it still doesn't work, I change the way you thought me. there was another person he say using first where method in app delegate let viewController = (window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController)?.children.first(where: { $0 is YourViewController }) but is still can figure out how to use the method

Comment: Looks like your structure is different. Can you share any demo project where this is not working?

Comment: this is the link my project http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=69614732438995826172 sorry I reverse back my code after it didn't work

Comment: I have checked your code and you have navigation controller added before your `ExploreViewController` thats why it's not working for you with my code. let me update my answer

Comment: I have added your project as well which is working.

Comment: Thank youuu very much, it work I have been stressful find the solution :)

Comment: Happy to help.. :)